# R LASSO always include some coefficient and question about data partition

Tags: r, logistic, lasso, glmnet

I have limited statistic knowledge but I am trying to conduct logistic regression by using a data with 300+ predictors. So I decided to use glmnet and LASSO. Below please see my code:

```
fit.lasso = glmnet(x, y,family="binomial",alpha = 1)
    plot(fit.lasso, xvar = "lambda", label = TRUE)
    cv.lasso = cv.glmnet(x,y,family="binomial",alpha = 1)
    plot(cv.lasso)
    coef(cv.lasso)
    cv.lasso$lambda.min
        bestlam = cv.lasso$lambda.min
    lasso.pred=predict(fit.lasso,s=bestlam,newx = x,type = "response")
```

I have two questions and appreciate any helps.

1. (removed since it was more related to purely programming question)
2. I have used CV to select lambda but I didn't partition the data into training and testing. Is it necessary since I have already used CV? I will need the `lasso.pred` to compare with actual to calculate the prediction accuracy.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: (+1) You can weight the predictors by overriding the `standardize` argument to `glmnet`.  With appropriate weights (applied manually by rescaling the values of each variable) you likely could get your predictors re-included, and (or but, depending on what you're trying to accomplish) they would still get regularized. This also begs the question of exactly which weights to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nicely done finding the answer to (1). This is precisely the answer that I would have provided.

The answer to (2) is to consider the nature of CV. The reason that we care about out-of-sample performance, i.e. use CV at all, is because our results will be biased if we train and test the model on the same data. What do you think that means for attempting to estimate RMSE when you have not held out any data from the LASSO procedure selecting $\lambda$?

Comment: thanks for your answer. I understand the reason to have hold-out data. I guess because I don't fully understand how `cv.glmnet` select lambda. Inspired by your answer, `cv.glmnet` would help us find the best and unbiased lambda for the training data, which may not be optimal one for testing data. In other words, `cv.glmet` helps find best regularized model for the training but it is not necessary the best one for testing, so the error rate may be different between training and testing.  is it correct?

Comment: Actually, what I'm getting at is that you'll want *two* CV loops to assess the error rate for the model: the inner one selects $\lambda$ and the outer one measures the RMSE for the selected $\lambda$.

Comment: got it. just curious, what if by doing outer CV, selected lambda causes a high error rate. Can we conclude that LASSO is not working well, we will need new data or more data transformation (e.g. polynomial, interaction). Because I noticed that if I don't set the seed, I will get a different `cv.lasso$lambda.min` each time when I run the loop. Should I keep experimenting different seed until the error rate is decent enough? Sorry for keep asking questions. You answers are inspiring.

Comment: the set.seed question is easily resolved: the data is randomly partitioned into folds, so you'll get different estimates. If these estimates vary widely, then you probably have a relatively small amount of data or a few strongly influential observations. Picking the seed on the basis of the performance is just lying to yourself: you're finding some configuration of partitions that does well -- this is just fitting a model to random variation and is not useful, cf p-value fishing.

Comment: Do you mind I ask you a follow-up question? When I tried to use `penalty.factor` in glmnet, it is not working for binary logistic regression. Do you have any suggestions? Error message please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35143975/r-logistic-glmnet-penalty-factor